# Onchange function not working in React Form with React-quill Editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, express

Thanks to whoever helps.

I'm using **react-quill** for the first time.

I'm trying to **save the notes the user writes on react-quill editor** but the **onChange()** function is working only for the input element of the React form but not for the ReactQuill component.

**When saving the notes with normal input it works.** Tested all my backend routes with postman so everything is working fine there. How can i go around this?

NotesEditor.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill"; // ES6
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css"; // ES6
import debounce from "../notes/helpers";
import NotesContext from "../../contexts/notes/notesContext";
import AlertContext from "../../contexts/alert/alertContext";
import AuthContext from "../../contexts/auth/authContext";

const NotesEditor = () => {
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
  const notesContext = useContext(NotesContext);
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { clearErrors } = authContext;
  const { setAlert } = alertContext;

  const {
    error,
    addNote,
    updateNote,
    clearCurrentNote,
    currentNote,
  } = notesContext;

  const [note, setNote] = useState({
    title: "",
    // notecontent: "",
  });

  const { title, notecontent } = note;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentNote !== null) {
      setNote(currentNote);
    } else {
      setNote({
        title: "",
        notecontent: "",
      });
    }
  }, [error, authContext, notesContext, clearErrors, currentNote]);

  const onChange = (e) => setNote({ ...note, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (title === "") {
      setAlert(`Please enter a title`, "danger");
    } else if (currentNote === null) {
      addNote(note);
    } else {
      updateNote(note);
    }
    clearAll();
  };

  const clearAll = () => {
    clearCurrentNote();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <h2>Write a note</h2>
        {/* <h2>{currentNote ? "Edit Contact" : "Add Contact"}</h2> */}
        <p>Please write something</p>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Note's Title"
          name="title"
          value={title}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <ReactQuill
          theme="snow"
          name="notecontent"
          value={notecontent}
          onChange={onChange}
        />

        {/* <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Please write a note here"
          name="notecontent"
          value={notecontent}
          onChange={onChange}
        /> */}

        <input
          type="submit"
          value={currentNote ? "Update Note" : "Add Note"}
          className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotesEditor;
```

Notes.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";
import Spinner from "../../components/layout/Spinner";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";

import NotesContext from "../../contexts/notes/notesContext";
import NotesForm from "../notes/NotesForm";
import NotesList from "../notes/NotesList";
import NotesEditor from "../notes/NotesEditor";

const Notes = () => {
  const notesContext = useContext(NotesContext);

  const {
    notes,
    currentNote,
    filteredNote,
    getNotes,
    loading,
    addingNote,
  } = notesContext;

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* <NotesFilter /> */}

      <NotesEditor />
      <NotesList />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Notes;
```

NotesState.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import NotesContext from "./notesContext";
import notesReducer from "./notesReducer";
import {
  GET_NOTES,
  ADD_NOTE,
  DELETE_NOTE,
  SET_CURRENT_NOTE,
  CLEAR_CURRENT_NOTE,
  UPDATE_NOTE,
  FILTER_NOTES,
  CLEAR_NOTES_FILTER,
  NOTE_ERROR,
  CLEAR_NOTES,
  ADDING_NOTE_STATE,
  UPDATE_NOTE_TITLE,
} from "../types";

const NotesState = (props) => {
  const initialState = {
    notes: null,
    currentNote: null,
    filteredNote: null,
    error: null,
    addingNote: false,
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(notesReducer, initialState);

  //Get Notes
  const getNotes = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("/api/notes");
      dispatch({ type: GET_NOTES, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTE_ERROR,
      });
    }
  };

  //Add Note
  const addNote = async (note) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/notes", note, config);
      dispatch({ type: ADD_NOTE, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.data.msg,
      });
    }
  };

  //changes state of adding note in state
  const addingNoteState = () => {
    console.log("addingNoteState funtion called");
    this.setState({ title: null, addingNote: !this.state.addingNote });
  };

  //Delete Note
  const deleteNote = async (id) => {
    try {
      await axios.delete(`/api/notes/${id}`);

      dispatch({ type: DELETE_NOTE, payload: id });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.msg,
      });
    }
  };

  //Update Note
  const updateNote = async (note) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.put(`/api/notes/${note._id}`, note, config);
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_NOTE, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.msg,
      });
    }
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_NOTE, payload: note });
  };

  const updateNoteTitle = async (note) => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      const res = await axios.put(`/api/notes/${note._id}`, note, config);
      dispatch({ type: UPDATE_NOTE_TITLE, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: NOTE_ERROR,
        payload: err.response.msg,
      });
    }
    dispatch({ type: UPDATE_NOTE, payload: note });
  };

  //Clear Notes
  const clearNotes = () => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_NOTES });
  };

  //Set Current Note
  const setCurrentNote = (note) => {
    dispatch({ type: SET_CURRENT_NOTE, payload: note });
  };

  //Clear Current Note
  const clearCurrentNote = () => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_CURRENT_NOTE });
  };

  //Filter Notes
  const filterNotes = (text) => {
    dispatch({ type: FILTER_NOTES, payload: text });
  };

  //Clear Filter
  const clearNotesFilter = (text) => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_NOTES_FILTER });
  };

  return (
    <NotesContext.Provider
      value={{
        notes: state.notes,
        currentNote: state.currentNote,
        filteredNote: state.filtered,
        error: state.error,
        getNotes,
        addNote,
        deleteNote,
        clearNotes,
        setCurrentNote,
        clearCurrentNote,
        updateNote,
        filterNotes,
        clearNotesFilter,
        updateNoteTitle,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </NotesContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default NotesState;
```

notesReducer.js

```
import {
  GET_NOTES,
  ADD_NOTE,
  DELETE_NOTE,
  SET_CURRENT_NOTE,
  CLEAR_CURRENT_NOTE,
  UPDATE_NOTE,
  FILTER_NOTES,
  CLEAR_NOTES_FILTER,
  NOTE_ERROR,
  CLEAR_NOTES,
  UPDATE_NOTE_TITLE,
  ADDING_NOTE_STATE,
} from "../types";

export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_NOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      };
    case ADD_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: [action.payload, ...state.notes],
        loading: false,
        addingNote: false,
      };
    case ADDING_NOTE_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: [action.payload, ...state.notes],
        loading: false,
        addingNote: !state.addingNote,
      };
    case UPDATE_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: state.notes.map((note) =>
          note._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : note
        ),
        loading: false,
      };
    case UPDATE_NOTE_TITLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: state.notes.map((note) =>
          note._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : note
        ),
        loading: false,
      };
    // (txt) => {
    //   console.log("updateNoteTitle Function: ", txt);
    //   this.setState({ title: txt });
    //   // };
    // };
    case DELETE_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: state.notes.filter((note) => note._id !== action.payload),
        loading: false,
      };
    case CLEAR_NOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: null,
        filtered: null,
        error: null,
        current: null,
      };
    case SET_CURRENT_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_CURRENT_NOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        current: null,
      };
    case FILTER_NOTES:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtered: state.notes.filter((note) => {
          const regex = new RegExp(`${action.payload}`, "gi");
          return note.name.match(regex) || note.email.match(regex);
        }),
      };
    case CLEAR_NOTES_FILTER:
      return {
        ...state,
        filtered: null,
      };
    case NOTE_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```